# SSE parallelization

Tags: c, parallel-processing, openmp, sse

Hi I am trying to improve the performance of this code, suposing that I have a machine capable of handling 4 threads. I first thought about making omp parallel but then I saw that this function was inside a for loop so creating threads so many times was not very efficient. So i would like to know how to implement it with SSE that would be more efficient:

```
unsigned char cubicInterpolate_paralelo(unsigned char p[4], unsigned char x) {
    unsigned char resultado;
    unsigned char intermedio;
    intermedio = + x*(3.0*(p[1] - p[2]) + p[3] - p[0]);

    resultado = p[1] + 0.5 * x *(p[2] - p[0] + x*(2.0*p[0] - 5.0*p[1] + 4.0*p[2] - p[3] + x*(3.0*(p[1] - p[2]) + p[3] - p[0])));
    return resultado;
}

unsigned char bicubicInterpolate_paralelo (unsigned char p[4][4], unsigned char x, unsigned char y) {
    unsigned char arr[4],valorPixelCanal;
    arr[0] = cubicInterpolate_paralelo(p[0], y);
    arr[1] = cubicInterpolate_paralelo(p[1], y);
    arr[2] = cubicInterpolate_paralelo(p[2], y);
    arr[3] = cubicInterpolate_paralelo(p[3], y);

    valorPixelCanal = cubicInterpolate_paralelo(arr, x);
    return valorPixelCanal;
}
```

this is used inside some nested for:

```
for(i=0; i<z_img.width(); i++) {
        for(j=0; j<z_img.height(); j++) {
            //For R,G,B
            for(c=0; c<3; c++) { 

                for(l=0; l<4; l++){
                    for(k=0; k<4; k++){

                        arr[l][k] = img(i/zFactor +l, j/zFactor +k, 0, c); 
                    }
                }

                color[c] = bicubicInterpolate_paralelo(arr, (unsigned char)(i%zFactor)/zFactor, (unsigned char)(j%zFactor)/zFactor);
            }
            z_img.draw_point(i,j,color);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Just nitpicking, but using SSE or another set of vector operations is called vectorisation and not parallelisation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've taken some liberties with the code, so you may have to change it significantly, but here's an (untested) transliteration to SSE:

```
__m128i x = _mm_unpacklo_epi8(_mm_loadl_epi64(x_array), _mm_setzero_si128());
__m128i p0 = _mm_unpacklo_epi8(_mm_loadl_epi64(p0_array), _mm_setzero_si128());
__m128i p1 = _mm_unpacklo_epi8(_mm_loadl_epi64(p1_array), _mm_setzero_si128());
__m128i p2 = _mm_unpacklo_epi8(_mm_loadl_epi64(p2_array), _mm_setzero_si128());
__m128i p3 = _mm_unpacklo_epi8(_mm_loadl_epi64(p3_array), _mm_setzero_si128());
__m128i t = _mm_sub_epi16(p1, p2);
t = _mm_add_epi16(_mm_add_epi16(t, t), t); // 3 * (p[1] - p[2])
__m128i intermedio = _mm_mullo_epi16(x,  _mm_sub_epi16(_mm_add_epi16(t, p3), p0));
t = _mm_add_epi16(p1, _mm_slli_epi16(p1, 2)); // 5 * p[1]
// t2 = 2 * p[0] + 4 * p[2]
__m128i t2 = _mm_add_epi16(_mm_add_epi16(p0, p0), _mm_slli_epi16(p2, 2));
t = _mm_mullo_epi16(x, _mm_sub_epi16(_mm_add_epi16(t2, intermedio), _mm_add_epi16(t, p3)));
t = _mm_mullo_epi16(x, _mm_add_epi16(_mm_sub_epi16(p2, p0), t));
__m128i resultado = _mm_add_epi16(p1, _mm_srli_epi16(t, 1)); 
return resultado;
```

The 16 bit intermediates that I use should be wide enough, the only way for information from the high bits to affect low bits in this code is the right shift by 1 (`0.5 *` in your code), so really we only need 9 bits, the rest cannot affect the result. Bytes wouldn't be wide enough (unless you have some extra guarantees that I don't know about), but they would be annoying anyway because there is no nice way to multiply them.

I pretended for simplicity that the input takes the form of contiguous arrays of `x`'s, `p[0]`'s etc, that's not what you need here but I didn't have time to work out all the loading and shuffling.

Answer (score 1):

SSE is quite unrelated to threads. A single thread executes a single instruction at a time; with SSE that single instruction may apply to 4 or 8 sets of arguments at a time. So with multiple threads you can also run multiple SSE instructions to process even more data.

You *can* use threads with for-loops. Just don't use them inside. Instead, take the `for(i=0; i<z_img.width(); i++) {` outer loop and split it in 4 bands of `width/4`. Thread 0 gets 0..width/4, thread 1 gets width/4..width/2 etc.

On an unrelated note your code also suffers from mixing floating-point and integer math. `0.5 * x` is not nearly as efficient as `x/2`.

Answer (score 0):

Using OpenMP, you could try adding the `#pragma` to the outer-most for loop. This should solve your problem.

Going the SSE route is trickier because of the extra alignment restrictions on data, but the easiest transform would be to extend `cubicInterpolate_paralelo` to handle multiple calculations at once. With enough luck, telling the compiler to use SSE will do the trick for you, but to make sure, you could use intrinsic functions and types.